# Obtener salida de dos numeros de una lista en python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente lista en python : [2,4,6,6,7,8]

Quiero obtener la siguiente salida :

```
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
(2, 6)
(2, 7)
(2, 8)
(4, 6)
(4, 6)
(4, 7)
(4, 8)
(6, 6)
(6, 7)
(6, 8)
(6, 7)
(6, 8)
(7, 8)
```

Éste es el código que realicé:

```
import itertools

li = [2,4,6,6,7,8]

sample = itertools.combinations(li,2)

for i in sample :
 print (i)
```

Me imprime perfectamente la salida. Sin embargo no me convence mucho usar teoria combinatoria para hacerlo.

Como puedo realizarlo sin usar la librería de combinatoria ? Una manera directa sin librerias ? Quizas con algun ciclo FOR ? . Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué "no te convence" mucho? Es una librería que forma parte de la biblioteca estándar, no hay que instalar módulos de terceros, y es muy eficiente. Más que hacerlo tú "a mano" mediante bucles. Por otro lado no usas "teoría combinatoria", simplemente llamas a una función que lo hace por ti, y que además está implementada internamente en C por lo que será mucho más rápida que una implementación en python.

Comment: Como estas otras vez @abulafia. En realidad estaba a punto de hacer un time.time para probar la big O de cada tecnica. Yo se que las librerías incluidas en python son muy eficientes porque estan creadas por los mejores . Pero me parecia que hacerlo con los ciclos FOR anidados sería como mas . .  Directo.

Comment: Quizas me falla un poco la intuición. Pero al decirme que está implementada internamente en C he entendido que quieres decir. Simplemente me parecia que agregar una libreria haria mas 'complejo' el programa. Pero como te dije la intuicion me falla.

Comment: Implementando el metodo time.time o cual sea, podré ver ese tiempo real correcto ?.  . Le agregaria mas elementos a la lista obviamente para que se vea mas obvio

Comment: He escrito una respuesta con lo que te estaba contando en los comentarios, para que sea más visible y tenga sitio de explicarme mejor.

Answer (score 3):

Traslado a una respuesta una discusión que estaba teniendo lugar en los comentarios, para que sea más visible, y de paso poder ampliar con datos esa discusión.

Se discutía qué solución es más eficiente en términos de velocidad, si usar `itertools.combinations()` o implementar uno mismo su propia solución con un par de bucles anidados.

Factores a tener en cuenta:

- Para generar las combinaciones de dos en dos, es necesario recorrer la lista dos veces, una para generar el primer elemento de cada tupla, y una segunda (para cada uno de los posibles segundos elementos), de forma anidada. Esto tiene complejidad O(N²) y no hay forma de hacerlo en menos pasos. Por tanto desde el punto de vista de la complejidad computacional usar `itertools` o nuestro propio bucle darían ambos la misma complejidad.
- Pero la complejidad es sólo una medida de cuántas operaciones es necesario hacer para resolver el problema, conforme aumenta el número de elementos en la entrada. No nos dice nada cuánto tarda cada una de esas operaciones (y por tanto del tiempo total). Aunque el tiempo total será proporcional al número de operaciones, quizás una implementación use operaciones más simples que requieren menos tiempo.
- De hecho esa es la situación real. `itertools` forma parte de la biblioteca estándar Python y está implementada en C, y por tanto compilada a código máquina. La solución basada en bucles propios estará implementada en python, ejecutada por un intérprete, y sus operaciones serán más lentas.
- Por otro lado la solución de `itertools` intenta ser mucho más genérica, pues permite no solo obtener parejas, sino tríos o cuádruplas o lo que se desee. Por tanto al ser una implementación más genérica contendrá seguramente más código para contemplar los diferentes casos. En este sentido cabe preguntarse si una implementación directa con bucles no sería más rápida.

La última palabra la tiene la experimentación. He cronometrado estas dos implementaciones. Para que salgan tiempos significativos hay que ir a listas de números muy largas (10000 elementos). Para ser justos con ambas soluciones tuve en cuenta lo siguiente:

- No imprimo cada combinación, pues se generan millones de ellas y cronometrar también el tiempo necesario para imprimirlas no aporta nada, pues sería el mismo en ambos casos.
- La solución `itertools` se limitará entonces a ir incrementando un contador por cada combinación generada, en lugar de imprimirla.
- La solución con los bucles anidados, además de incrementar ese contador, debe extraer la pareja de elementos de la lista `numeros`, para generar el par deseado. No hacer eso sería injusto para la solución `itertools` que sí que extrae la tupla deseada en cada iteración aunque luego no hagamos nada con ella.

Por tanto estos son los códigos probados:

```
# Solucion con itertools

numeros = list(range(10000))

i = 0
for combinacion in combinations(numeros, 2):
  i+=1
print(i)
```

Salida: 49995000
Tiempo: 6.85s

```
c = 0
for i in range(len(numeros)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(numeros)):
    combinacion = (numeros[i], numeros[j])
    c += 1
print(c)
```

Salida: 49995000
Tiempo: 14.4s

Vemos que se confirma lo esperado. La solución con itertools es más rápida (poco más del doble) que la de los bucles.

### Bonus

Esta es una gráfica que muestra cómo el tiempo necesario crece a medida que aumentamos el tamaño de la lista de entrada, para cada una de las implementaciones. Ambos crecimientos son exponenciales, y por tanto tienen la misma Big-O, pero los coeficientes que afectan a cada exponencial son diferentes, cosa que no recoge la Big-O y que se traduce en la diferencia de tiempos observada.

[image: Grafica]

### Ampliación

Por petición del OP incluyo el código que genera  la gráfica anterior:

```
from itertools import combinations
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Implementar y cronometrar la versión que usa itertools
def con_itertools(numeros):
  i = 0
  for combinacion in combinations(numeros, 2):
    i+=1
  return i

# t1 es la lista de tiempos medidos para cada tamaño de la entrada
t1 = []
for n in range(100, 2000, 2):
  numeros = list(range(n))
  t = time.time()
  con_itertools(numeros)
  t1.append(time.time()-t)

# Análogamente cronometro y almaceno tiempos para la implementación con bucles
def con_bucles(numeros):
  c = 0
  for i in range(len(numeros)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(numeros)):
      combinacion = (numeros[i], numeros[j])
      c += 1
  return c

t2 = []
for n in range(100, 2000, 2):
  numeros = list(range(n))
  t = time.time()
  con_bucles(numeros)
  t2.append(time.time()-t)

# Finalmente pinto la gráfica
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(t1, label="con itertools")
plt.plot(t2, label="con bucles")
plt.ylabel("Tiempo (segundos)")
plt.xlabel("Tamaño de la lista")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Entiendo abudafia.  En realidad muchisimas gracias. No solo lo leí sino que Lo estudiaré.. una pregunta por curiosidad : que usaste para graficar las big O

Comment: Hice un bucle que llamara al método de itertools varias veces, con tamaños de lista cada vez mayores, cronometrando cada llamada y guardando los tiempos en una lista. Luego hice lo mismo con el método de los bucles anidados. FInalmente usé `matplotlib` con esas dos listas de tiempos, para hacer la gráfica. Si estás interesado puedo poner el código que generó la gráfica.

Comment: Claro Abulafia. Me gustaría muchísimo ver el código que generó la grafica para tratar de estudiarlo.

Comment: @NIN Pues hecho. He ampliado la respuesta para incluir el código que mide los tiempos y genera la gráfica

Answer (score 1):

Dos ciclos anidados, el primero desde el elemento `0` hasta el `último`, y el segundo desde el `elemento actual+1` hasta el `último` pueden hacer las parejas de datos que buscas:

```
lista = [2,4,6,6,7,8]

t = len(lista)
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(i+1, t):
        print((lista[i], lista[j]))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias aeportugal. Es perfecto.Me has hecho pensar en esa tecnica. No es un simple FOR anidado sino que tiene unos pequeños detalles que los estudiaré.